# change bootstrap default column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to replicate this 
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MzsD.png)
and so far this is my
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYpMN.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 content">
                <h1>Meet BestApp</h1>
                <h1>The new world for chat</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deleniti cumque odit atque molestiae totam facere aliquam sed cum perspiciatis quam, at sequi, corporis distinctio. Fugit nam, nesciunt quaerat pariatur.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form">
                <h2>Sign Up!</h2>
                <form action="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Adress*">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1">
                        <label for="cbox1">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i'm using bootstrap grid system to achieve this but the form section is too wide 
and i couldn't figure out how to change the width, is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: so use col-md-3 or col-md-4 instead of col-md-6

Comment: Use `col-md-7` and `col-md-5`, or `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`

Comment: In stead of using `col-md-6` two times, use `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 content">
      <h1>Meet BestApp</h1>
      <h1>The new world for chat</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deleniti cumque odit atque molestiae totam facere aliquam sed cum perspiciatis quam, at sequi, corporis distinctio. Fugit nam, nesciunt quaerat pariatur.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form">
      <h2>Sign Up!</h2>
      <form action="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Adress*">
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <br>
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1">
          <label for="cbox1">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```